# ORA-01924 while giving Grant role to user

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

I am facing an issue for which I tried searching for solutions online but not getting anywhere.

So basically we have a legacy systems where traditionally the Grants where given directly to users.
But now the DBAs are not allowing the same and are asking to give grant to particular Roles only.

I tried doing that on Database 1 and after that I came to know that I have to give Grant for role to the User as well, which I did on Database 1 and it is working fine.

However when I am repeating same steps on Database 2, I am not able to give Grants for role to User, giving me error "ORA-01924"

--Database 1---

--connect as SCHEMA1

> CREATE TABLE SCHEMA1.TEST1 (ID INT);

> GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA1.TEST1 TO EXISTING_ROLE1;

> GRANT EXISTING_ROLE1 to USER1;

-- Connect as USER1

> select  * from SCHEMA1.TEST1; --Working fine

---

--Database 2---

--connect as SCHEMA1

> CREATE TABLE SCHEMA1.TEST1 (ID INT);

> GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA1.TEST1 TO EXISTING_ROLE1;

> GRANT EXISTING_ROLE1 to USER1;

Error:

> ORA-01924: role 'EXISTING_ROLE1' not granted or does not exist
> 00000 -  "role '%s' not granted or does not exist"
> *Cause:    Either the role was not granted to the user, or the role did not exist.
> *Action:   Create the role or grant the role to the user and retry
> the operation.

---

I compared DBA_ROLES table for this role in both databases.
Database1

```
+----------------+----------+--------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------+------------+-----------+----------------+
|      ROLE      |  ROLE_ID |  PASSWORD_REQUIRED |  AUTHENTICATION_TYPE |  COMMON |  ORACLE_MAINTAINED |  INHERITED |  IMPLICIT |  EXTERNAL_NAME |
+----------------+----------+--------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------+------------+-----------+----------------+
| EXISTING_ROLE1 |      214 | NO                 | NONE                 | NO      | N                  | NO         | NO        |                |
+----------------+----------+--------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------+------------+-----------+----------------+
```

Database2

```
+----------------+----------+--------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------+------------+-----------+----------------+
|      ROLE      |  ROLE_ID |  PASSWORD_REQUIRED |  AUTHENTICATION_TYPE |  COMMON |  ORACLE_MAINTAINED |  INHERITED |  IMPLICIT |  EXTERNAL_NAME |
+----------------+----------+--------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------+------------+-----------+----------------+
| EXISTING_ROLE1 |      237 | NO                 | NONE                 | NO      | N                  | NO         | NO        |                |
+----------------+----------+--------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------+------------+-----------+----------------+
```

So obviously either SCHEMA1 is missing some Grant or EXISTING_ROLE1 setting is different. But I am not able to figure out what is missing.
Any tips on how can I overcome this error.

Comment: Did you check whether EXISTING_ROLE1 actually *exists* in database **2**?

Comment: yes, it exists and I can see it under "dba_roles"

Comment: Check whether the schema1 user has the role itself in both DBs, and whether it has the admin option to allow it to grant that role to others.

Comment: Normal users cannot grant roles. If you were able to do that as `schema1` then either `schema1` had the role `with admin option`, or it has the `grant any role` system priv. Most likely it is missing this in the other database.

Comment: @PaulW @Alex- You are right. I worked with another DBA and he asked me to execute `select * from session_roles` to compare roles in both DB. Looks like Database1 had some extra roles which were not allowed. So they offered to run `GRANT EXISTING_ROLE1 to USER1;` on database 2 from as Admin. Thanks